# API Plattform including a referenced DTO in a custom DTO from a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, dto, api-platform.com

I have created a custom DTO for API Plattform and I included in this DTO a "subarray" which points to a custom DTO that is defined in a Bundle. It works, but /api/docs does not show the linked type:

```
<?php

namespace App\Dto;

use App\Entity\Client;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use PTF\CacheBundle\Dto\CachedUserRepresentation;

class ClientRepresentation
{
    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 10)]
    public string $id;

    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 10)]
    public string $extid;

    #[Assert\NotBlank()]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 80)]
    public string $name;

    #[Assert\Length(max: 80)]
    public ?string $contact = null;

    #[Assert\Length(max: 80)]
    public ?string $street = null;
    
    #[Assert\Length(max: 20)]
    public ?string $zip = null;
    
    #[Assert\Length(max: 80)]
    public ?string $city = null;
    
    #[Assert\Length(max: 2)]
    public ?string $country = null;
    
    #[Assert\Length(max: 80)]
    public ?string $email = null;

    /** @var CachedUserRepresentation[] */
    public array $linkedUsers = [];


     /**
     * 
     * @param string $id
     * @param string $name
     * @param ?string $contact
     * @param ?string $street
     * @param ?string $zip
     * @param ?string $city
     * @param ?string $country
     * @param ?string $email
     * @param ?Collection $linkedUsers
     */
    public function __construct(
        string $id,
        string $name,
        ?string $contact,
        ?string $street, 
        ?string $zip,
        ?string $city,
        ?string $country,
        ?string $email, 
        ?Collection $linkedUsers,       
    ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->extid = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->contact = $contact;
        $this->street = $street;
        $this->zip = $zip;
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->country = $country;
        $this->email = $email;

        if ($linkedUsers === null) $this->linedUsers = [];
        else  $this->linkedUsers=$linkedUsers->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param Client $client
     * @return ClientRepresentation
     */
    public static function fromClient(Client $client): ClientRepresentation
    {
        return new ClientRepresentation(
            id: $client->getId(),
            name: $client->getName(),
            contact: $client->getContact(),
            street: $client->getStreet(),
            zip: $client->getZip(),
            city: $client->getCity(),
            country: $client->getCountry(),
            email: $client->getEmail(),
            linkedUsers: $client->getLinkedUsers(),
        );
    }
}
```

CachedUserRepresentation is defined in the PTF\CacheBundle. But API-Plattforms /api/docs just shows that:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "extid": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "contact": "string",
  "street": "string",
  "zip": "string",
  "city": "string",
  "country": "st",
  "email": "string",
  "linkedUsers": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

or

[image]

I tried also:

- to add it as collection ==> not working.
- to create a local class extending the class PTF\CacheBundle\Dto\CachedUserRepresentation ==> not working